# Shopify liquid template: On-click shows same address on different Address Icon's

Tags: jquery, loops, conditional-statements, shopify, liquid

My End goal is,When I click on first Address Icon It must show the address map bind to it as `Iframe` same with second one.I have successfully added dynamic class to the Address Icons as `address`then I also successful with on Address Icon click Google map is getting loaded. Main problem is I am getting either of map location i.e `Wink & Nod` on both time or `Abhiruchi Mall`. I have checked this by changing value of `i` value in `for` loop by changing it to `0` or `1` and changing less than condition, also i shuffled switch case `0` or `1`. I am 99% successful with it but on click on both Icons loading same Maps. When I click on first Address Icon `Wink & Nod` map must be shown and when I click on second Icon `Abhiruchi Mall` must be loaded.Currently they are loading same address on click of both Icons.Thanks.

Shopify liquid template

```
<div class="container main content main-wrapper">
  {% if section.settings.image == nil %}
    <h1 class="center">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <div class="feature_divider"></div>
  {% endif %}

  <div class="sixteen columns featured_links">
    <div class="section clearfix feature">
      {% for block in section.blocks %}
        <div class="{% if section.settings.featured_promos_per_row == 2 %}eight columns {% cycle 'alpha', 'omega' %}{% elsif section.settings.featured_promos_per_row == 3 %}one-third column {% cycle 'alpha', '', 'omega' %}{% else %}four columns {% cycle 'alpha', '', '', 'omega' %}{% endif %} {% if section.settings.featured_links_style != blank %}{{ section.settings.featured_links_style }} {% cycle 'delay-025s', 'delay-05s', 'delay-075s', 'delay-1s' %}{% endif %} center">
          {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
            <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}">
          {% endif %}

          <div class="{% if section.settings.rounded_image != blank %}rounded{% endif %}">
            {% if block.settings.image != nil %}
              <img  src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x' }}"
                    alt="{{ block.settings.image.alt }}"
                    data-src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }}"
                    class="lazyload"
                    {% comment %} data-sizes="auto" {% endcomment %}
                    data-srcset=" {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }} 2048w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '1600x' }} 1600w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '1200x' }} 1200w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '1000x' }} 1000w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '800x' }} 800w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '600x' }} 600w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '400x' }} 400w"
                     />
            {% else %}
              {% capture i %}{% cycle "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" %}{% endcapture %}
              {{ 'collection-' | append: i | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg placeholder-svg--promotions' }}
            {% endif %}
          </div>

          {% if block.settings.title != blank %}
            <h3>{{ block.settings.title | escape }}</h3>
            {% if section.settings.show_divider %}
              <div class="feature_divider"></div>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
            </a>
          {% endif %}

            {% if forloop.index <= 2  %}
                <div class="address"></div>
            {% endif %} 

          {% if block.settings.text != blank %}
            {{ block.settings.text }}
          {% endif %}
        </div>

        {% if section.settings.featured_promos_per_row == 2 %}
          {% cycle '', '<br class="clear " />' %}
        {% elsif section.settings.featured_promos_per_row == 3 %}
          {% cycle '', '', '<br class="clear" />' %}
        {% else %}
          {% cycle '', '', '', '<br class="clear" />' %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% if section.settings.contact_address != blank %}
    <br class="clear" />
    <div class="embed-container maps">
        <iframe width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q={{ section.settings.contact_address | replace: ' ', '+' }}&amp;z={{ section.settings.zoom_level }}&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>
    {% endif %}    
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Code onClick load google Map

```
<style>    
.address{
    position: absolute;
    left: 234px;
    bottom: 160px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 115px;
}
</style>

<script>   
$('.address').click(function(){
for(var i=0;i<=$('.address').length;i++){
            switch (i) {            
                case 0 :
                 $('.embed-container, .maps').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d945.7084267048235!2d73.8854388291583!3d18.536415399212462!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xdda3387f821de029!2sWink+%26+Nod!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1525613363322" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>'); 
                break;
                case 1 : 
                $('.embed-container, .maps').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3784.450403270009!2d73.81459871445705!3d18.463246687442403!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bc2956a20fbac17%3A0x91987f7033fd2e3c!2sAbhiruchi+Mall+and+Multiplex!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1525612885113" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>'); 
                break;    
                default:
                $('.embed-container, .maps').html(' <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d945.7084267048235!2d73.8854388291583!3d18.536415399212462!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xdda3387f821de029!2sWink+%26+Nod!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1525613363322" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>'); 
                break;     
            }
        }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored my script to this and it worked like charm !!!

```
$('.address').click(function(){
   var j=$('.address').index(this);    
  switch (j) {            
                case 0 :
                 $('.embed-container, .maps').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d945.7084267048235!2d73.8854388291583!3d18.536415399212462!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xdda3387f821de029!2sWink+%26+Nod!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1525613363322" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>'); 
                break;
                case 1 : 
                $('.embed-container, .maps').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3784.450403270009!2d73.81459871445705!3d18.463246687442403!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bc2956a20fbac17%3A0x91987f7033fd2e3c!2sAbhiruchi+Mall+and+Multiplex!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1525612885113" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>'); 
                break;    
                default:
                $('.embed-container, .maps').html(' <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d945.7084267048235!2d73.8854388291583!3d18.536415399212462!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xdda3387f821de029!2sWink+%26+Nod!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1525613363322" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>'); 
                break;     
            }

  });

</script>
```